# Answering Angular requests with restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, angularjs, restify

So I am trying to build a restify backend to answer these Angularjs calls. The problem is that angular sends the data via Request Payload (Chrome Dev Tools | no idea what that is).

Angularjs call:

```
var userDetails = {
   username:"username",
   password:"password"
}
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/login',userDetails,{}).success(function(data){});
```

As far as I know with restify I can only access data saved in the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/login/username/password
```

Here I would just use:

```
server.post("/login/:username/:password", function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

But how can I access the Request Payload?

If that is not possible can I get Angular to make the calls to fit restify.

Comment: Have you enabled the `restify.bodyParser` plugin or have you looked in `req.body`?

Comment: no I dont have the bodyParser enabled

Comment: That worked. Just me being stupid again. Thanks :D